# Add Flatr button to Sharing option

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, buttons, social-sharing, sharing

I know adding a Flatr button to the sharing option is possible on wordpress.com and I wondered if there is a way to do so on a self hosted wordpress ?

If not, do I have to create my own plugin or is there one good plugin you guys would recommend ?

Comment: What is "sharing option" in context of WP org site?.. Please note that plugin recommendation are considered not in scope here.

Comment: @Rarst my wordpress dashboard is not in English, but what I call "sharing option" is in settings --> Sharing. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I would guess that is specific to dot com though, there is no native sharing functionality in dot org.